# Amadeus Access Token Error, Mandatory grant_type form parameter missing

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, amadeus

I am trying to get access token using Amadeus testing API using Postman, but it return error in response. Can you please help me where something is missing or incorrect.

URL: https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MY_API_Key&client_secret=MY_API_Secret
Header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Method: Post

Response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Mandatory grant_type form parameter missing",
    "code": 38187,
    "title": "Invalid parameters"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the grant_type, API key, and API secret should be passed as body parameters and not URL parameters.

Please take a look at the [Authorization Guide](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/authorization-262).